# Looping a slider backward in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

I am building a custom looping slider with the "next/prev" arrow.

Actually, my NEXT (1->2->3..) is working the elements are fine but when it comes to loop backward PRV (1->3->2..) the animation run but the last element does not follow until it call the callback function.

Even the callback place the "next" one.

For exemple, I press PREV and I am on the slide #1, I want the slide #3 to follow..

```
function slide() 
        {
            $('.next').click(function slideNext()
            {
                // Animate left
                $this.animate({'left' : '-' + $this.parent().width()}, options.speed, function()
                {
                    // Return css left:0 and call the next slide
                    $this
                        .css('left', 0)
                        .children(':first')
                        .appendTo($this); 
                })
            });// End slideNext()

            $('.prev').click(function slidePrev()
            {   

                // Animate right
                $this.animate({'left' : '+' + $this.parent().width()}, options.speed, function()
                {
                    // Return css left:0
                    $this
                        .css('left', 0)
                        .children(':first')
                        .appendTo($this); 

                })
            });// End slidePrev()
        }
```

Comment: Would you mind share your html&css as well ? using jsfiddle.net ...

Comment: **http://www.okidoo.ca/client/tactic/site/**

For the moment